# Optimizing loading numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization, ram

I have a dataset of "images" saved as numpy arrays (.npy files). I say "images" because in reality the shape of this array is (some_height, some_width, 6), it would be like a 6-channel image. They all have different height and width to save space, because each array has information about objects of different size. However, I am training different ML models and for that I need them all to have the same shape.

I programmed the functions to load and resize all objects and it works, the thing is that it consumes a lot of RAM. And it works in colab pro for about 500 objects (using about 15Gb of RAM) but I would like to load more objects to train a good model. The resize function creates an array of zeros with the maximum height and maximum width that I have and places the object in the center.

Here are the functions:

```
def loads_dataset(path):

x = []
y = []
names = []

for folder in os.listdir(path):
  #print(folder)
  for file_ in os.listdir(os.path.join(path, folder)):
    #print(file_)
    array = np.load(os.path.join(os.path.join(path, folder), file_))
    x.append(array)
    if folder == "Class 1":
      y.append(0)
    elif folder == "Class 2":
      y.append(1)
    elif folder == "Class 3":
      y.append(2)

return x, y

def resize(grains):
    
    """
    Pads all grains to have the height of the highest grain and the width of the widest grain.
    
        Parameters:
            grains (list): List of grains.

        Returns:
            resized_grains (list): List of pad grains.
    """
    
    max_height = 0
    max_width = 0
      
    for i in grains:
        if i.shape[0] > max_height:
            max_height = i.shape[0]
        if i.shape[1] > max_width:
            max_width = i.shape[1]
      
    resized_grains = []
    
    for j in grains:
        
        matrix = np.zeros((max_height, max_width, j.shape[2]))
        
        x_start = int((max_width/2) - (j.shape[1] / 2))
        y_start = int((max_height/2) - (j.shape[0] / 2))
    
        
        matrix[y_start:y_start + j.shape[0], x_start: x_start + j.shape[1],:] = j       
        
        resized_grains.append(matrix)
        
    return resized_grains, max_height, max_width
```

Is there a better way to do this, that consumes less RAM? I have thought about using numpy arrays instead of python list but the issue is that I don't know the number of objects I am going to have, and that's why I use .append. Saving the resized images and then uploading them again is not the best option either because those 500 .npy files weigh about 20 Gbc in total.

I've also read about modules like pickle but I don't know if this would work or how to implement it.

Comment: Why about downsampling the larger ones to arrive at a (small) standard size for all "images"? That's typically how real images are processed for machine learning. Otherwise you could store them as [sparse matrices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html).

Comment: you should be able to calculate final ram use - number of arrays times their size. You can't reduce that, unless your model can work with batches.  The only other thing you  watch out for is temporary arrays.

Comment: @a_guest the images are not so big they usually fit in 500x500, and I would lose information of each object, but thank you

Comment: @JulianVega Discarding information might not be a problem if the level of needed detail isn't that high. For example image classification can be successful with 64x64 images. Thus, I just wanted to mention this option of downsampling.